# What does the Python logo mean?

Tags: python

I know this question is not fully programmatic, but I know many are wondering the same thing, so I will go ahead and say it: what does the Python logo mean? Someone get it?

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You mean this one? I think it's just supposed to look like two snakes (pythons).
[image]

Comment: Neat, I'd never spotted that before. I thought it was just an abstract +.

Comment: me too, I kinda see them now.

Comment: Also, if you unfocus your brain just right, you can see the blue snake as an uppercase P and the yellow as a lowercase y: Py.

Comment: @RussellBorogove, I see the lowercase `y` just fine... but how is the blue snake a `P`?

Comment: Remove the upper half of the vertical stroke and the left half of the top horizontal of the P.

Answer (score 2):

Don't you see it? They're two snakes (two pythons maybe?)..

By the way, I don't think they've any particular meaning, instead I'm wondering how many people think about this thing :P

Answer (score 0):

it is a snake symbol, look closely you can see the eye and tail